# How do I count number of occurrences in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do I count number of occurrences in a list and store the word and count value as a dict using python without using Counter function from collection library?
E.g.: `list = [a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c,c]` result should be when I print dict a->3  b->2 c->4:

```
dict=[(word,list.count(word)) for word in list]
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), then you can try dict comprehension combined with [set()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#sets.Set) to avoid counting occurrences of the same word many times:

```
>>> lst = list("aaabbcccc")
>>> lst
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
>>> {word: lst.count(word) for word in set(lst)}
{'a': 3, 'c': 4, 'b': 2}
```

Just keep in mind that while this method is pretty nice and clear, it's not the most efficient method and if your list is very large, you should use something faster.

Comment: You are calculating count multiple time for each word which is obviously redundant. You can use `{word: lst.count(word) for word in set(lst)}`

Comment: Yes, that's more efficient for sure